# Is there a way to stop company users from creating their own Azure DevOps Organizations separate from the main Organization?

Tags: azure-devops

We're having a lot of developers just sign up for Azure DevOps, create their own Org, and use the five free licenses. This creates big problems if they were to leave. Is there a way to stop this or at least be notified when this happens?

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to prevent it that I'm aware of. You should definitely ensure that everyone is using organization accounts ("work or school" as opposed to "personal" accounts) and that your Azure DevOps organization is backed by Azure Active Directory, so that at the very least you can retain access to any accounts created by others.

However, there's nothing wrong with creating an account to use as a sandbox. In fact, it's very common, as it can be useful to have an unrestricted place to try out features.

If people are creating additional accounts and then using them for real work on an ongoing basis, it sounds like you have a "people problem" in your organization that needs to be addressed, not a tooling problem.

- Are people not being given appropriate access to the place they should be working in a timely fashion? This points to a problem with on-boarding.
- Are people unaware of where they should be working? This is a training/documentation problem.
- How are they working in a personal account without other collaborators (such as managers, teammates, or business users who are managing the backlog) being aware of it? If their manager/technical lead *is* aware of it, why is their manager/technical lead not redirecting them to an appropriate location? This represents a communication problem (specifically, **lack** of communication).